# Why won't this firebase updateProfile return an error no matter what

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

This firebase update profile promise won't return an error even if it's not updated.

It updates perfectly though. But I want to display an error if something goes wrong.

```
$scope.firebaseUser.updateProfile({
            displayName: $scope.userName   
        }).then(function() {
            $scope.messageshow = true;
            $scope.message = 'Profile Updated Successfully!';

        }, function(error) {
            $scope.indicator = false;
            $scope.messageshow = false;
            $scope.error = error.message;
 });
```

Comment: An error will show if something goes wrong. So if something hasn't gone wrong (which anything getting updated, doesn't mean error happened) error message won't contain anything. How about logging error to console instead?

Comment: I tried passing an empty string, it didn't update but showed no error!

Comment: Are you sure Firebase is returning an error when empty string is passed? You should do a console.log in both success and error handlers and see which gets called

Comment: Update profile does not validate display name or photoUrl. You will have to do that on the front end.